# Canceled a transaction and no longer saw my ether in metamask wallet

Tags: transactions

I was sending 14.793776530278380275 ($5,744.42 at the time) worth of ether over to binance. I set the gas fee to be at the max and waited for the transaction for around 10+ minutes. Due to this I thought there as an issue and decided to cancel. After that I no longer saw my balance on my meta mask.

Transactions
0x8461b92a9f168075e6d6219bf15c2d1bf2c7f589350057504500c61d0a34685b

dropped and replaced

0x9984d0478d6270625bd2f5c589c34803e09f2e5d2a7efedcb3b54ae9af8e8f15

Comment: Have you try to check en Etherscan the amount of ethers you currently have on your address ?

Comment: How do I check that?

Comment: Yes I did I don't see it on my metamask

Comment: I can see on Etherscan (https://etherscan.io/address/0xc01341e39ed25ae64804ec9cbd0a39ac11ea7c13) there are 31 ethers on your address. Is it the correct amount ? Does Metamask still displays a wrong value for your ethers ?

Comment: I have done a few other trades and have 31 ethers now. I am still missing the 14 I should've had. Metamask only shows the others that I have done.

Comment: Ok so the amount displayed by Etherscan is correct (no funds lost) but the one displayed on Metamask is false, is it right ? In this case you can try asking directly on their github.

Comment: No hold on my etherscan is still missing the 14 that I lost.